# Не изменяется StringVar в функции

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Моя проблема такова: у меня не меняется переменная var, когда я вызываю функцию profile_tab(name_profile) из другого файла

```
def p2(upanel):
   def select_button_clicked():
       selection = list(profile_user_list.curselection())
       selection.reverse()
       if len(selection) == 0:
           error_label['text'] = "Выберите анкету"
       else:
           prof_list = list(profile_user_list.get(0, 
                           profile_user_list.size()))
           profile_tab(str(prof_list[selection[0]]))

upanel = Tk()
upanel.title("UserPanel")
upanel.geometry("600x500")
```

Когда ту же самую функцию вызывать в том же файле через profile_tab("Имя") все работает, как часы

```
def profile_tab(name_profile):
  var = IntVar()  # Переменная с вариантами ответов

  def change():
      answer_prof = ""
      if var.get() == 1:
          answer_prof = var1
      elif var.get() == 2:
          answer_prof = var2
      elif var.get() == 3:
          answer_prof = var3
      elif var.get() == 4:
          answer_prof = var4
      print(var.get())
      return answer_prof

  user_panel = Tk()
  user_panel.title("Анкетирование на тему: " + '"' + name_profile + '"')
  user_panel.geometry("600x500")
  user_panel.resizable(False, False)
  with open(r"ProfileList\{}.txt".format(name_profile), "r") as 
                open_profile:
      for line in range(page):
          quest = open_profile.readline()
          var1 = open_profile.readline()
          var2 = open_profile.readline()
          var3 = open_profile.readline()
          var4 = open_profile.readline()
  open_profile.close()
  question_name = Label(user_panel, font="Arial 20", text=quest)
  question_name.place(x=50, y=50)

  radiobutton_var1 = Radiobutton(user_panel, text=var1, variable=var, value=1)
  radiobutton_var2 = Radiobutton(user_panel, text=var2, variable=var, value=2)
  radiobutton_var3 = Radiobutton(user_panel, text=var3, variable=var, value=3)
  radiobutton_var4 = Radiobutton(user_panel, text=var4, variable=var, value=4)
  radiobutton_var1.place(x=50, y=150)
  radiobutton_var2.place(x=50, y=200)
  radiobutton_var3.place(x=50, y=250)
  radiobutton_var4.place(x=50, y=300)
  next_button = Button(user_panel, text="Следующий вопрос", width=20, height=1,
                     command=change)  # тут next_button_clicked, answer для проверки
  next_button.place(x=400, y=450)

  user_panel.mainloop() 
profile_tab("Имя")
```

Comment: А почему вы думаете, что из другого файла вызываете именно эту функцию?

Comment: import secondFile, `secondFile.profile_tab(str(prof_list[selection[0]]))`

Comment: @Эникейщик окно открывается и все radio-button там есть, однако переменная var всегда принимает значение 0

Comment: Скорее всего вы создаете дочернее окно с помощью `Tk()`. Если так делать, то переменные tk для дочерних окон будут работать криво. Чтобы работало правильно, дочернее окно нужно создавать через `Toplevel()`.